# Can a solenoid be made of copper strips?

Tags: electromagnetism, copper, electromagnet

Could a coil of copper strips instead of copper wires be used as a solenoid? Are there any real world examples of making solenoids out of strips of copper?

[image: copper tape]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely, copper foil is often used to wind inductors and transformers due to low AC resistance, a solenoid is no different.  You can see an example [here](https://www.parts-express.com/Jantzen-8375-1.2mH-14-AWG-Copper-Foil-Wax-Coil-255-565?quantity=1&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=18127373971&gclid=CjwKCAiAr4GgBhBFEiwAgwORrYoGieUfATO1ejjhIbfS8xTvGIMwflEYnPx0DD_IKuWBrUCTvV_TNBoCwVwQAvD_BwE) (and below).
[image]

Of course you have to insulate the foil to avoid shorts, and it doesn't buy you much over a conventional solenoid at low excitation frequencies.  Interwinding capacitance can be in issue in some applications as well.

Comment: I mean, you're likely to get a higher fill factor than with round, especially for thicker foil with very thin insulation (such as enamel); that buys you something. It does roll off at modest frequencies, where eddy currents in the sheets force currents to their edges (and even more so in the middle of the coil (proximity effect)).  There are also rectangular and square shape magnet wires available.

Comment: @TimWilliams agreed- Better fill factor for sure. Foil can be great for a 1 turn secondary in a transformer, but proximity losses and interwinding capacitance get ugly with lots of turns. It's as always all about the tradeoffs...